# extjs 4 : how to set the listview identity and pop up the id in the message box

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

```
Ext.require([
    'Ext.grid.*',
    'Ext.data.*',
    'Ext.panel.*'
]);
Ext.onReady(function(){
    Ext.define('ImageModel', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: ['id', 'url', {name:'size', type: 'float'}, {name:'lastmod', type:'date', dateFormat:'timestamp'}]
    });
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
        model: 'ImageModel',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'get-images.php',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'images'
            }
        }
    });
    store.load();

    var listView = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        width:425,
        height:250,
        collapsible:true,
        title:'Simple ListView <i>(0 items selected)</i>',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

        store: store,
        multiSelect: true,
        viewConfig: {
            emptyText: 'No images to display'
        },

        columns: [{
            text: 'File',
            flex: 50,
            dataIndex: 'id'
        },{
            text: 'Last Modified',
            xtype: 'datecolumn',
            format: 'm-d h:i a',
            flex: 35,
            dataIndex: 'lastmod'
        },{
            text: 'Size',
            dataIndex: 'size',
            tpl: '{size:fileSize}',
            align: 'right',
            flex: 15,
            cls: 'listview-filesize'
        }]
    });

    // little bit of feedback
    listView.on('selectionchange', function(view, nodes){
        //pop up message on here.no idea
    });
});
```

### Question

1)how to set the listview row identity ID from the database?when the listview row are selected, will pop up the message show the ID are selected.but the ID column are not able to show.must be hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the File column from the column config and use the code that I put in the selectionchange event here:

```
Ext.require([
    'Ext.grid.*',
    'Ext.data.*',
    'Ext.panel.*'
]);
Ext.onReady(function(){
    Ext.define('ImageModel', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: ['id', 'url', {name:'size', type: 'float'}, {name:'lastmod', type:'date', dateFormat:'timestamp'}]
    });
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
        model: 'ImageModel',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'get-images.php',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'images'
            }
        }
    });
    store.load();

    var listView = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        width:425,
        height:250,
        collapsible:true,
        title:'Simple ListView <i>(0 items selected)</i>',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

        store: store,
        multiSelect: true,
        viewConfig: {
            emptyText: 'No images to display'
        },

        columns: [{
            text: 'Last Modified',
            xtype: 'datecolumn',
            format: 'm-d h:i a',
            flex: 35,
            dataIndex: 'lastmod'
        },{
            text: 'Size',
            dataIndex: 'size',
            tpl: '{size:fileSize}',
            align: 'right',
            flex: 15,
            cls: 'listview-filesize'
        }]
    });

    // little bit of feedback
    listView.on('selectionchange', function(view, nodes){
        var nodeIdDisplay = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++)
        {
            if(nodeIdDisplay.length > 0)
                nodeIdDisplay += ",";
            nodeIdDisplay += nodes[i].get("id");
        }
        alert(nodeIdDisplay);
    });
});
```